# Error in SQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I an trying to run an SQL query in visual studio asp.net but I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' AND JobID = jn.ID GROUP BY JOBID)) as Delivered,
>                          ' at line 1

But I can't see where the problem is.

```
private static string SearchSQL
{
    get{
        return @" set @sql = null;
            select
                group_concat(distinct
                    concat(
                        'max(case when PieceType = ''',
                        PieceType,
                        ''' then AdvisedQty end) AS ',
                        concat(PieceType)
                    )
                )into @sql
            FROM customer c
            LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
            JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = ''Debtor''
            LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
            LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID

    WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compid;

    set @sql = concat('select 
                c.Name,
                COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
                SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''DEL'' AND JobID = jn.ID GROUP BY JOBID)) as Delivered,
                SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''POD'' AND JobID = jn.ID GROUP BY JobID)) as POD,
                (select COUNT(job_debriefs.ID) from job_debriefs WHERE JobID = jn.JobNo) as Debriefs,
                sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
                SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
                SUM(jn.CBM) as CBM,
                jn.Department,
                (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =3 AND JobID = jn.ID) as CollectName,
                (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =2 AND JobID = jn.ID) as DeliverName,
                ', @sql, ' 
            FROM customer c
            LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
            JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = ''Debtor''
            LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
            LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID

    WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compid
    GROUP BY c.ID');

    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
                            ";
        }
    }
```

Ok I fixed the single quotes but now the error coming up is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?compid
>                                                           GROUP BY c.ID' at line 19

It is finding the compid so thats not the problem

Comment: you may get a more useful error message if you attempt to run the SQL code in your DBMS directly.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy I tried running the query in MySQL Workbench but that gave the error:  `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max(case when PieceType = 'Carton' then AdvisedQty end) AS Carton,max(case when ' at line 13`

Comment: is there a reason why you have double parentheses around that line?  You should only need one (this might not be the issue, but try it with single parens)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any extraneous single ' when putting your code directly into MYSQL

Comment: you forgot to add second single quote to escape: Status = ''DEL'' and Status = ''POD''

Answer (score 0):

You're still inside a string literal here, so you need to double up the single quotes to escape them on the `DEL` value just ahead of the excerpt in your error message:

```
SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''DEL'' AND JobID = jn.ID GROUP BY JOBID)) as Delivered,
SUM((select COUNT(ID) from jobstat where Status = ''POD'' AND JobID = jn.ID GROUP BY JobID)) as POD,
```

Comment: Do I need to do that for `'Debtor'` to?

Comment: ok thanks. But there's another error: `near '?compid
                                                        GROUP BY c.ID'`